# Matching Javascript escaped form data in python

Tags: javascript, python, regex, validation, python-unicode

I am trying to do some data validation using regex in python (2.7). From client side (javascript) I for example receive the following string:

```
name = u'B\xf8tte'
```

I want to match this using the following pattern (or similar), allowing only A-Z characters including latin variants:

```
pattern = '^([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)$'
```

This works when matching is done client side (javascript), given value:

```
var value = 'Bøtte';
```

Is this due to differences in how javascript and python escapes this kind of characters (http://www.charbase.com/00f8-unicode-latin-small-letter-o-with-stroke), specifically "\u00f8" vs "\xf8"?

Is there some other pattern that would work both for javascript/python? I might be missing something in the encoding/decoding?

**MCVE:**

Note, the pattern is the same both client and server side and matches client side, but not server side.

Value "Bøtte" is matched (again, client side), while "Bøtteひ" is not matched.

Client:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="no">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var pattern = '^([A-Za-z\-\.\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)$';
        var value = $(this).find('input').val();

        if (new RegExp(pattern).exec(value)) {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/',
              data: $(this).serialize(),
              dataType: 'json',
          }).done(function(result) {
            console.log('DONE')
          }).fail(function() {
            console.log('FAIL')
          });
        } else {
          console.log('INVALID FORMAT');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
 </head>

 <body style="background: #CCC;">
  <form method="post" action="/">
   <input type="text" name="test" value="Bøtte" style="margin: 20px; font-size: 2rem;">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" name="Submit" style="margin: 20px; font-size: 2rem;">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Server:
    # Imports
    import re
    import json
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify

```
# App
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True


# Route: Index
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {}
        # VALIDATE
        for field in request.form.keys():
            value = request.form[field]

            pattern = '^([A-Za-z\-\.\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)$'
            match = re.match(pattern, value)

            data[field] = {
                'value': value,
                'match': True if match else False
            }

        print json.dumps(data, indent=4)

        return jsonify({'foo':'bar'})

    else:
        return render_template('index.html')


# Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Comment: JavaScript sees everything as a _wide_ character. This means that `\xf8` and `\u00f8` match the same character. The character unit is UTF-16. So, it all depends on the  _width_ of the character unit.

Comment: Btw, the Unicode 9 Latin script is these char's `[\u0041-\u005a\u0061-\u007a\u00aa\u00ba\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u02b8\u02e0-\u02e4\u1d00-\u1d25\u1d2c-\u1d5c\u1d62-\u1d65\u1d6b-\u1d77\u1d79-\u1dbe\u1e00-\u1eff\u2071\u207f\u2090-\u209c\u212a-\u212b\u2132\u214e\u2160-\u2188\u2c60-\u2c7f\ua722-\ua787\ua78b-\ua7ae\ua7b0-\ua7b7\ua7f7-\ua7ff\uab30-\uab5a\uab5c-\uab64\ufb00-\ufb06\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a]` Be sure to add the Unicode regex modifier.

Comment: What is exactly the problem? This pattern matches that name in both python and javascript. Could you please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about how you were attempting it?

Comment: I've added a sample of what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\xYY` in both JavaScript ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/shyDO7/1)) and Python ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/shyDO7/2))

```
^([A-Za-z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xf6\xf8-\xff\s]*)$
```